# Creación de función en postgresql con retorno dinámico

Tags: sql, postgresql, funciones, plsql, plpgsql

Lo que quiero hacer es una función en posgresql con retorno dinamico, en Oracle se hace algo asi

```
create or replace FUNCTION consultapersona(CODIGO IN NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS     
    v_return SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
    OPEN v_return for SELECT id, nombre from persona where id=codigo;
RETURN v_return;
END consultapersona;
```

y en postgresql hasta donde entiendo se tiene que hacer asi

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."persona"()
  RETURNS SETOF "public"."persona" AS $BODY$
    SELECT * FROM persona;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000
```

lo que quiero hacer es que sin importar los datos que quiera retornar (como en el caso de Oracle) pueda retornarlos, y no tenga que crear una vista o una tabla para poder retornar estos datos según este formato.

quiero hacer una función en Postgresql dinamica, donde sin importar la consulta que quiera retornar.¿es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá va un ejemplo que espero que te ayude. A tu pregunta la respuesta es:

1. postgres es fuertemente tipado, una función siempre debería devolver una cantidad fijas de columnas (siempre los mismos tipos y los mismos nombres).
2. Si se necesita poder devolver cualquier cosa se puede devolver un objeto json (o un arreglo o una tabla de columnas json) pero no se parece a lo que estás preguntando.
3. No es necesario tener una tabla igual a lo que se quiere devolver, se puede especificar las columnas declarando un tipo para usarlo de retorno.
4. Las comillas para los nombres no son necesarias si se quieren nombres en minúsculas sin acentos, eñes, espacios ni signos.
5. Public tampoco es necesario (salvo que se esté apuntando a otro lado con "set search_path").

Va un ejemplo ilustrativo y un link a una página para poder ver cómo anda. Si necesitas más cosas intenta poner un ejemplo con datos ilustrativos en esa página u otra similar.

```
create table personas(
    id integer primary key,
    apellido text not null,
    nombre text not null,
    pais text
);

insert into personas values (1, 'Vargas Llosa', 'Mario', 'pe');
insert into personas values (2, 'García Márquez', 'Gabriel', 'co');
insert into personas values (3, 'Borges', 'Jorge Luis', 'ar');
insert into personas values (4, 'Soriano', 'Osbaldo', 'ar');

create type escritores_paises_t as (
    id integer,
    nombre_y_apellido text
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION escritores_pais(p_pais text) RETURNS setof escritores_paises_t
AS 
$BODY$
begin
  return query SELECT id, nombre||' '||apellido nombre_y_apellido
    FROM personas
    WHERE pais=p_pais;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Para verlo andar: https://rextester.com/NGYXJD6876

También se podía usar language sql (como habías intentado) y funciona también (y más rápido).